# Few strings are failed to encrypt using AES256 in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, sha256

This specific case is coming whenever i tried to encrypt single char strings in application. When i tried to encrypt the same string with main method then i was able to encrypt it. But when i run with the application then this specific issue is coming. I felt this is strange because it is working with the main method.

My encryption code will be as follows.

```
public static String encryptWithAES256(String strToEncrypt) throws Exception
{
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] encodedhash = digest.digest(KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(KEY.getBytes(),16));
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedhash, AES_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(CHARACTER_ENCODING))));
}
```

Comment: If it's failing in production, but not when run in isolation, something you removed when trying to make example shorter is causing your issue. Try testing your code with multiple threads as those arecommon in production environments, but frequently skipped when making the example easier

Comment: Ferrybig I'm facing this issue even running with single thread also. This was happening for single char strings

Comment: Is there any possibility for input string and encrypted string both can be same ? In my case this is happening.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the system would give out the same text as what is being put up, you are using Base64 encoding the output, this increases the data by 33%, rounded up

Comment: Using key as iv is very bad (unsafe) practice. You need to provide more informationm and code to get any reasonable answer.  `input string and encrypted string both can be same` - no, that is very unlikely (=impossible), seems you have a problem somewhere else too